# How to ignore, or discard overlayed dialog box on website?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I try to parse 
[this site](https://www2.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=CN&category=equityindex)
with chromedriver
But there's a dialog box that messes up with that

[image: SGX site]

Is there a way to discard the dialog box or choose the `No, thanks` button?

Comment: What problem are you running into?  Can you post the selenium-webdriver code that you've written to solve this issue?

Comment: I am not sure how to search for the dialog box, then how to extract from there the "No thanks" button to then click it?

Not sure what the Xpath of that button would be?

Comment: You can wait and click a simple CSS selector, `button[data-analytics-action='Click Cancel']`, to dismiss the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()`on the element with text as **No, thanks** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www2.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=CN&category=equityindex")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.sgx-button--link[data-action='cancel'][data-analytics-action='Click Cancel']"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www2.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=CN&category=equityindex")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sgx-button--link' and @data-action='cancel'][@data-analytics-action='Click Cancel']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: SGX]